# how remove ComponentsList's subpanel?

Tags: inno-setup

Under the WizardForm.ComponentsList there is a panel that i would like to remove or hide,

[image]

I don't care about labels, i just want only the componentlist.
how to? thanks

Comment: That's not a subpanel but its parent, the `SelectComponentsPage`. And no, they cannot be transparent if that would be your next question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was late, but try this:

```
WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage.Visible := False;
```

Comment: Won't this hide the whole page including its child controls ?

Comment: Hiding page will hide all their components. If you want to hide only components but not the page, so you need to enumerate all components.

Comment: what about:     WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Parent = WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage.Parent